# Unable to fetch the complete data using vision api

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

```
 $web_detection = $vision->image($imageData, ['WEB_DETECTION']);
 $imageFeatures[] = $web_detection;
 $data = [];
 $results = $vision->annotate($web_detection);
```

I am using this piece of code to fetch the data from vision API for matching pages, but I always got only 10 results, whereas in google vision official website the dataset is large than the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a max_results field in Feature field of the API.

By default it is set to be 10, but you can tune it.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature

Seems you can add that field by changing the way to construct an image:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-vision/blob/v0.19.3/src/Image.php

```
* $imageResource = fopen(__DIR__ . '/assets/family-photo.jpg', 'r');
 * $image = new Image($imageResource, [
 *     'FACE_DETECTION',
 *     'LOGO_DETECTION'
 * ], [
 *     'maxResults' => [
 *         'FACE_DETECTION' => 1
 *     ],
 *     'imageContext' => [
 *         'latLongRect' => [
 *             'minLatLng' => [
 *                 'latitude' => '-45.0',
 *                 'longitude' => '-45.0'
 *             ],
 *             'maxLatLng' => [
 *                 'latitude' => '45.0',
 *                 'longitude' => '45.0'
 *             ]
 *         ]
 *     ]
 * ]);
```

Comment: How to pass the same maxResults , when using library via composer